# CMake C:/IntelSWTools/ISSM_2016/tools/compiler/gcc-ia/5.2.1/bin/i586-intel-elfiamcu-gcc is not a full path to an existing compiler tool

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-errors, cmake

I am having issues compiling this project on zephyr.js, the instructions on their GitHub are for Linux however they do have an environment setup for Windows as well which I have completed to the letter.

When I run the compilation using the makefile I get:

`CMake C:/IntelSWTools/ISSM_2016/tools/compiler/gcc-ia/5.2.1/bin/i586-intel-elfiamcu-gcc is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.`

I am using the msys terminal with MinGW and I have installed CMake separately and configured it... but why is it throwing this error? I have checked, and the file is actually there. If I type `C:/IntelSWTools/ISSM_2016/tools/compiler/gcc-ia/5.2.1/bin/i586-intel-elfiamcu-gcc.` into the terminal, it also executes the compiler successfully.

Any ideas?

(Before anyone tells me to try on Linux, for now, it is a requirement to use Windows for this project)

Comment: Did you miss to add the `.exe` extension in your path? Switching to Linux would help in this case...

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it. A switch to linux seems probable if we can't get the toolchain to work on windows

Comment: Check the CMakeError.log.

Comment: There was the exact same question on the mailing list in 2014: https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2014-August/thread.html#58222

Comment: It doesn't output anything to the CMakeError.log, also I've checked that but there doesn't seem to be any solution